# Upload File Using Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Dears 
I'm a ASP.NET Developer , i search for a way that i can upload files using Javascript pure with asp.net web forms and i found it so poor ,i don't need it in jquery / i have searched for things for my purpose and i found methods that can help but i don't know how to fit it to my purpose knowing that i don't need any post backs  [Methods like ] sendAsBinary its in XMLHTTPREQUEST OBJECT Supported by firefox and getAsBinaryData and its a method in the file DOM Element Object also supported only by firefox ,
i wish that some one can help me find a way to do the upload with pure javascript

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

Something like what you're trying to do is only possible with the [HTML5 file api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader)(which allows reading files). I've never had to do something like this before, but I suggest:

```
//file is ready for sending
var file = fileInput.files[0];
var fReader = new FileReader();

fReader.onloadend = function(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //processing and send 
  this.result;
};

fReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: well thanks for your help yes its what i want to send the data with what ever format base64 or binary to the server but I'm going crazy i don't find the compatible way with all browsers and also I'm going crazy i don't know how jquery do it all i do is going around with iframe :( putting all upload stuff there but i wana find it in Javascript 

thanx again i know its a strange issue and solutions is all around with jquery  but i wish find it as i think in javascript pure with older version of HTML :)