# Flash image uploading and editing

Tags: php, javascript, image, flash, actionscript-2

How would I go about making a flash image uploader/editor in ActionScipt 2, not 3? I want the user to be able to upload a PNG or JPG image and then display it on the screen. They can then crop it, and if possible, add text and use other normal editing tools. I have an idea on how to do this, but I'm not quite sure on some parts. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

well, if I was you I would separate this task into two,
so one will be the uploading on images, and then the next is to create the cropping and editing..

Unless you want to make the whole project in actionscript, the fundamentals are still the same. If so then just find some file uploading thing in actionscript.

**Uploading** 
So look up on how to make a simple uploading project, So you will come across "AJAX", I have done a few it's very easy, but its also good if you use "jquery" if you want to use ajax (so you don't have to reload the page every time the user has to upload a image) there are millions of tutorials and examples on the internet, after you get this working without any problems then you have to work out the fundamentals of the project, for example how am I going to crop the image, use javascript (Im pretty sure you can't but worth a look around, well you will be able to do it action script I think.)

so here is some examples of file uploading..

Without reloading the page "AJAX" 
I use this one, when I was learning it was really helpful.
[nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) 
[csstrinks](http://css-tricks.com/ajax-image-uploading/) 
[zurb](http://www.zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload)

with reloading the page
[SO...purejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523714/upload-file-using-pure-javascript) 
[Purejs](http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html)

The next Task is making the whole editing and cropping bit and intergrate it with your test upload project

**Editing**
Just make the ui up in flash and google the stuff you don't know how to do...
Im not very good with actionscript so I can't help you there.

But if you want a javascript way, then you will have to do the cropping server side as javascript can't (as far as I know) do cropping.

and editing Im not quite sure what you are meaning by this, but If you want simple editting like, changing brightness then use google and search it up, im sure someone has done it..

**Remember** when in doubt Google it out :-P